# how to determine the accuracy of a number in vba? How many decimal places does a number have?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way to tell how accurate a number is. For example If I had x=3.14, I need to write code that can tell that 3.14 is accurate up to the 1 one-hundreths. Or if I had x= 31300, I would need to know that x was accurate only to the hundreds place?

EDIT: Maybe accurate was a poor choice of word. I'm using a Bisection algorithm to find the root of a polynomial that I've fit to some x,y coordinates. I need to provide an degree of accuracy (DOA) that tells the algorithm when it has gotten close enough to the actual root to stop. So if the data is given as 12.1, I would want my DOA to be +/- 0.01.

Comment: but x might actually *be* 31300.

Comment: How "accurate" it is depends highly on the specific value being stored. Can I ask what possible value this information might have for you? (Why do you think you need this?)

Comment: VBA uses floating point numbers, therefore 3.14 and 3.139999999 can actually have the same value internally. You can't determine the accuracy of a floating point number because there is a whole range of numbers that actually match this value.

Comment: a double value on a PC is good to 15/16 decimal places. Problems come if you do things with numbers of vastly differing magnitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers have various representation in computing, and non-integer numbers are either represented with floating points or fixed points.

Unfortunately, there is no native fixed-point type in VBA.

For Single and Double, VBA uses [IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), which uses a base 2 exponent for its internal representation. Therefore, 0.01 for example cannot have an exact value (but VBA hides it from you)

```
Debug.Print 0.1 * 0.1 = 0.01 ' Prints False
```

There is another type called `Decimal` with a base 10 exponent.
Unfortunately you cannot declare a variable of `Decimal` type, you need to use a `Variant`.
[CDec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199018.aspx) can be used to convert a String, Integer, Double, etc.., to a Decimal

```
Debug.Print CDec(0.1) * CDec(0.1) = CDec(0.01) ' Prints True
```

We know that for `Decimal` the precision is up to 28 digit after decimal. To determine the position of the first non-zero digit, we just need to divide the number by 10 until the rounding happens

```
Function ndec(n As Variant) As Variant
    Dim n1 As Variant
    Dim n2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    n1 = CDec(n)
    n2 = n1

    If n1 = 0 Then
        ndec = CDec(0)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Do
        n1 = CDec(n1 / 10)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While CDec((n1 * 10 ^ (i Mod 28)) * 10 ^ (i - i Mod 28)) = n2 ' it should be CDec(n1 * 10 ^ i) = n2 but 10^i overflows when i > 28 so we split the operation

    ndec = CDec(10 ^ (i - 29))
End Function
```

Usage :

```
ndec(1.34) ' returns 0.01
ndec(12340) ' returns 10
```

---

### Additionnal information

You need to be very careful though with the precision of floating points as 2 numbers can have the same representation:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long: i1 = 16777221: i2 = 16777220
    Dim f1 As Single, f2 As Single: f1 = 16777221: f2 = 16777220
    Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double: d1 = 16777221: d2 = 16777220

    Debug.Print "Integer soustraction : " & i1 - i2 ' printf 1
    Debug.Print "Single soustraction : " & f1 - f2 ' printf 0
    Debug.Print "Double soustraction : " & d1 - d2 ' printf 1
End Sub
```

More information:
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use the WorksheetFunction.Round(arg1, arg2).
arg1 is the number to evaluate;

arg2 is the rounding accuracy; positive for right of the decimal, negative for left of the decimal.

Let your algorithm evaluate arg1 (not rounded) and return a new result, arg3(not rounded).  Then compare the rounded algorithm result (arg3), with the rounded original (arg1), using the precision you want (arg2)

The line of code you need for the comparison is

```html
If WorksheetFunction.Round(arg1, arg2) = WorksheetFunction.Round(arg3, arg2) Then 
'your next steps here
```

You can see the effect of the Round function with the code below which passes arg1, increments it to arg3, then compares the rounded arg1 and arg3 values

```html
Public Sub test()

Dim arg1 As Double
Dim arg3 As Double
Dim arg2rounded
Dim arg3rounded

arg1 = 1652.23564
Do While 1 = 1
    arg3 = AlgResult(arg1) 'send a value to your algorithm routine
    Debug.Print "arg1 not rounded = " & arg1 & "  arg3 not rounded = " & arg3
    For arg2 = -4 To 4 'loop through presicion to see effect
        arg1rounded = WorksheetFunction.Round(arg1, arg2)
        arg3rounded = WorksheetFunction.Round(arg3, arg2)
        If arg1rounded = arg3rounded  Then
            Debug.Print arg1rounded & " = " & arg3rounded & " at desired precision of " & arg2
            Else: Debug.Print arg1rounded & " <> " & arg3rounded & " at desired precision of " & arg2
        End If
    Next
    arg1 = arg3
Loop
End Sub

Public Function AlgResult(EvalNum As Double) As Double

    AlgResult = EvalNum + 0.5

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B = A / (Left(A, InStr(1, A, ",") - 1) & Mid(A, InStr(1, A, ",") + 1, 30))
or
B = A / Replace(A, ",", "")
```